# How can I grab the ID passed to a Django REST API?

Tags: python, django, rest

I am building a Django application that exposes a REST API by which users can query my application's models. I'm following the instructions [**here**](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart#testing-our-api).

My Route looks like this in myApp's url.py:

```
from rest_framework import routers
router = routers.DefaultRouter()    router.register(r'myObjects/(?P<id>\d+)/?$', views.MyObjectsViewSet)
url(r'^api/', include(router.urls)),
```

My Serializer looks like this:

```
class MyObjectSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyObject
    fields = ('id', 'name',)
```

My Viewset looks like this:

```
class MyObjectsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = MyObjects.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['id'])
    serializer_class = MyObjectSerializer
```

When I hit /api/myObjects/60/ I get the following error from the first line of the Viewset:

```
name 'self' is not defined
```

Why?? How do I grab the ID of 60 in my viewset and get fetch the MyObject with that ID?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use ViewSet as oppose to ModelViewSet. The code below should do what you need unless there is a strong reason to use ModelViewSet. If you go to the URL of say `http://yourdomain/yourmodel/10` the pk variable will have a value of 10.

```
class YourModelViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):

     def retrieve(self,request,pk=None):
         u = request.user
         queryset = YourModel.objects.filter(user=u,pk=pk)
         if not queryset:
             return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
         else:
             serializer = YourModelSerializer(queryset)
             return Response(serializer.data,status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Thanks - Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks! This looks like what I need. Can you please tell me what module I need to import to get Response()?

Comment: Here's the import - from rest_framework.response import Response

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using `viewsets.ModelViewSet` Django Rest Framework handles all the filtering of specific objects for you. Change your `queryset` property to `MyObjects.objects.all()`.

Overriding `queryset` as others suggested will break the `/myObjects/` route because the `id` does not exist.

Comment: I don't care about the /myObjects/ route. I only need the /myObjects/60/ route to work. But when that happens, I want this API to return MyObjects.objects.get(pk=60).myFunction(). How do I make that happen?

Answer (score 2):

If you want (or need) to stick with `viewsets.ModelViewSet`, you can still access the id from the `kwargs` argument of the action methods.

```py
class MyObjectViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

     def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        obj_id = kwargs['pk']
        obj = MyObject.objects.get(pk=obj_id)
        # Do your thing
        # Send back response
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logger line is referencing self, but there is no self in that context (you are at class level, not inside a method). Try removing the logger line.

Comment: Can you show me how I should do it if I want queryset to be set to the value of the myObject with pk=60? queryset = Profile.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['id']) gives me the exact same error.

Comment: Edited the question accordingly to more clearly show the issue.